# Secondary Name Node not starting on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hdfs

I have installed Hadoop via command line in GCP as well as all its components and my secondary name doesn't run when I execute JPS.  All the other Daemons run fine.  What could be the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you put the error message with your question!

Comment: Could you please share the error you got? Could you also share the guides/documentation you followed to try and achieve this?